# How to use angular file upload in glyphicon?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open local file using bootstrap glyphicon so i am trying to use this example https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/ but its not working, Any idea how can i use this approach with images like glyphicon ?

main.html

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"><input type="file" file-model="myFile"/></span></a></li>
```

mainCtrl.js

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            console.log('file is ' );
            console.dir(file);
            var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.You need to use label since using span is outdated

> [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/6242/)

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open">  Browse
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" style="display: none;"/> </label></a>
```

Similarly you can add for the upload button also

Comment: for some reason its not opening window may be because its inside list element in my code what you think ?

Comment: thanks i resolved the issue with little change on your code.